# SQL code giving errors ORA-01403, ORA-06512, ORA-04088 when using an insert statement with a where clause

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I'm trying to insert new rows in a table using the below SQL code. However, I seem to get errors ORA-01403: no data found, ORA-6512, and ORA-04088: error execution of trigger.

I've run the select statement in isolation and it runs as expected with the correct data being output. When I include the insert statement it seems to error.

Is there any obvious mistakes in this script?

```
INSERT INTO mem_care_bn (
    client_ref, 
    member_ref, 
    employment_ref, 
    benefit_ref, 
    date_updated, 
    updated_by, 
    benefit_code, 
    date_fr, 
    date_to, 
    benefit_total,
    trans_control,
    unique_ref
)
SELECT 
    mcb.client_ref, 
    mcb.member_ref, 
    '1', 
    '1', 
    mcb.date_updated, 
    'USERA',
    'PMABC', 
    mcb.date_fr, 
    mcb.date_to, 
    mcb.benefit_total,
    mcb.trans_control,
    mcb.unique_ref
    
FROM 
    mem_care_bn mcb
    JOIN mem_view mv1 ON mv1.member_ref = mcb.member_ref
WHERE 
    mcb.benefit_code = 'POMAIN'
    AND mcb.employment_ref = mv1.employment_ref
    AND mv1.status = 'Z'
    AND mv1.scheme IN ('BOL', '005')
    AND mv1.member_ref IN (
        SELECT mv2.member_ref 
        FROM mem_view mv2
        WHERE mv2.status = 'A'            
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM mem_care_bn mcb2
            WHERE mcb2.member_ref = mv2.member_ref
            AND mcb2.employment_ref = mv2.employment_ref
            AND mcb2.benefit_code NOT IN ('PMABC') OR mcb2.benefit_code IS NULL
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your problem is in Trigger which is set on mem_care_bn